# How do I erase the LUKS headers in terminal?

Tags: luks, rm, disk-management

I am wondering if erasing the LUKS headers (primarily the one on the active booted partition/disk) is as simple as doing a `sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root` or if I'd need to do a different command. Which would it be?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer this method to delete the LUKS header:- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Drive_preparation#Wipe_LUKS_header